# Cant get logo to appear in right place plus cross-browser issues

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Twitter bootstrap wordpress theme. I want the logo (the picture of a face) to appear next to the title of the blog. I've tried both absolute and relative positioning as well as other css styles, but i cant get the logo to appear in the right place without either extending the height of the toolbar, or inadvertently affecting an adjacent element.

How do i fix the css so the logo appears correctly in all browsers and does not inadvertently affect any other element?

Here is the source from the header.php, the toolbar is being generated in the body and positioned at the top of the page.

```
<div class="container-fluid nav-container">
                        <nav role="navigation"><img style="z-index: 10; position:absolute; margin-left: -235px" src="http://blog.freeteacher.co.uk/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap-V2.1/images/logo_small.png">
                            <a class="brand" id="logo" title="Fun Learning for Children | Resources for Parents and Teachers" href="http://blog.freeteacher.co.uk">FreeTeacher – Blog</a>

                            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </a>

                            <div class="nav-collapse">
                                <ul id="menu-main" class="nav"><li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://blog.freeteacher.co.uk/about/">About</a></li>
```

```
                        </nav>

                                                    <form class="navbar-search pull-right" role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://blog.freeteacher.co.uk/">
                            <input name="s" id="s" type="text" class="search-query placeholder" placeholder="Search">
                        </form>

                    </div>
```

Here is a link to the css file which is just the twitter bootstrap css
http://blog.freeteacher.co.uk/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap-V2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

Also - here is the page where this is being rendered

http://blog.freeteacher.co.uk/news/getting-to-know-each-other/

Comment: Post your CSS with the question, post only the rendered HTML ('view source') because PHP is ***entirely irrelevant*** to JavaScript, it works with HTML on the client side. And, if possible, please use [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to post a demo we can work with. Include the actual image file, too. Just for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my tests in Firebug, if you change the inline styling for the `<img>` element from `margin-left:-235px;` to `left:35px;` you end up with what you're seeking. You can adjust the value from 35px in order to get it exactly where you want. To be positive that it is always where you want, it could be worthwhile to also set `top: 0;` but that is probably not necessary.

For reference, this works because you have `position:absolute;` set, which means that it will position the element in reference to the first container element that has a position assigned, or to the document as a whole if (as in this case) there is no such parent element. Thus setting `top:0; left:35px;` tells the browser to place the image 0 pixels down from the top left corner and 35 pixels to the left.

Comment: Is there a way, I could get this to simultaneously work for the mobile version of the site? I notice that on the mobile version by applying the margins as above (since it's absolute positioning) the logo is obstructing the blog title. Any tips or pointers?

Comment: Well, you could always have a separate version for mobile. Or you could use PHP to detect if it is a mobile browser and then have the PHP write different inline dimensions if it is.

Comment: The wordpress theme is using twitter bootstrap so it has mobile detection built in, right? so should i just eek out the code that is mobile specific and change the dimensions on that?

Comment: I haven't done a lot with wordpress themes, so I can't say for sure, but to me that sounds like a good direction to go.